# Как получить стоимость доставки посылки через Почту России?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как рассчитать стоимость и сроки доставки груза из Москвы до Санкт-Петербурга, используя API Почты России?

Comment: [Расчет стоимости пересылки](https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/nogroup-rate_calculate)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтоп.

Comment: @freim, почему offtop?

Comment: @Grundy, насколько я понимаю, с этим лучше обращаться в поддержку ПР, нет? Собственно, вы же сами дали ссылку.

Comment: @freim, этак можно большую часть вопросов закрыть с рекомендацией обратиться в поддержку :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, временами граница достаточно размытая. Но в данном случае мне все же кажется, что сайт ПР более правильное место для поиска ответов.

Comment: @freim Аргументы? Почему вопрос "Не могу найти в документации MDN" можно, а "не могу найти пример API" - нельзя?

Comment: @A K, у меня нет формального обоснования (у вас, я думаю, тоже). Если вы считаете, что вопрос закрыт не по правилам, подавайте на переоткрытие. Лично я голосовать против переоткрытия не буду. Если вас комьюнити поддержит, значит так тому и быть.

Comment: У них вообще есть публичное api?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну какое-то апи определенно есть

Comment: @Grundy, не факт, в мобильном приложении, например, я такого функционала не видел.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну как бы выше ссылка на вполне себе апи :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ааа, я не смотрел. Ну круто тогда. Там и примеры есть, в чем тогда проблема ТС не понятно

Comment: @Grundy а вопрос поправить не? Чтоб по комментам не скакать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так вопрос вроде норм :-)

Answer (score 3):

Следуя описанию [документации](https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/nogroup-rate_calculate), для расчета стоимости нужно отправить post запрос на следующий адрес:

```
"https://otpravka-api.pochta.ru/1.0/tariff"
```

В теле запроса передаются необходимые данные, описание возможных полей так же есть в документации.

Кроме того, необходимо добавить следующие заголовки:

1. "Content-Type": "application/json",
2. "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
3. "Authorization": "AccessToken " + access_token,
4. "X-User-Authorization": "Basic " + login_password

Также в документации есть [пример запроса на языке Python](https://otpravka.pochta.ru/specification#/nogroup-rate_calculate_py)

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще ссылка для тех, кому интересно и кто не знал до сих пор, на официальный калькулятор Почты России стоимости доставки и, как вишенка на торте, расчета доставки с учетом возврата практически любых типов отправлений, проходящих через ПР:

[Тарификация услуг и контрольные сроки доставки отправлений](https://delivery.pochta.ru/)

Более того, в этом калькуляторе можно делать поправку стоимости доставки/возврата на дату (подключается справочник тарифов на ту дату, которая нужна). Плюсом еще идет вывод стоимости как с НДС, так и без НДС. Вводите все нужные данные, а внизу окна выдается готовая ссылка для API - вставляете в свой код и высчитывайте на автомате. Либо просто через свой парсер настраиваете подстановку нужных индексов, дат и категорий отправлений и получаете стоимость.